# "Adaptive" normalization to 0-1? Decoding the 0s and 1s from an array of values (low level barcode decoding)

Tags: computer-vision, pattern-matching, barcode

I am working on a decoder of a black-white tag (very similar to a bar code).

What the decoder gets are already separated cells of the barcode and each one white and black reference cell.

The basic idea is to calculate the mean brightness of each cell and compare it to the reference values, in order to tell whether it is a 0 or a 1. The problem is the inconsistent lightning, so a white cell on e.g. the left can be nearly as grayish as a black cell on the right. So the values you get is something like:

80, 81, 79, 47, 77, 80, 68, 82... (which would represent W,W,W,B,W,W,B,W...). The 68 is closer to the white reference value, but since there is an 80 and an 82 to the left and to the right, it obviously has to be black.

What would be the most elegant way to decode the 0s and 1s not by comparing them strictly to the two reference values, but from the pattern of the values?

Best, Pawel

Comment: Do you mean strictly from the pattern, or some combination of the two?

Comment: Could be both. One could use the reference values as an orientation to which "amplitude" could be expected. Or one could pre-process those values, finding local minima/maxima and "normalizing" the other values (?) and then compare it to the reference values. Just some thoughts I had, but no actual idea what's the algorithm I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "elegant" solution:

1. Apply some sort of blur to the matrix you've been given.
2. Subtract the blurred matrix from the original matrix.
3. Add this difference, scaled by some factor, to the original matrix.

Steps 1 and 2 create a matrix with values representing the difference from nearby values. Combining this data with the original values gives the original matrix some extra information.

Comment: Thank you. This really is an elegant, simple yet very effective solution. PS. A typo though: I assume you meant subtracting the blurred matrix from the original one.